# Scroll Right Simulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on rtl. My markup is:

```
<div class="data_header">
   <div class="data_scroll_head">
     <table class="table"></table>
    </div>
   <div class="data_scroll_body">
     <table class="table"> </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I'm scrolling the body I set the header margin-left/margin-right. The margin depedents on a direction.

```js
var offset = $(e.currentTarget).scrollLeft();
e.data.$('.data_scroll_head table').css('margin-left', -1 * offset);
e.data.options.offset = offset;
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question, anyway what does this has to do with backbone.js...?

Comment: Please google it. MDN javascript scrollLeft and try to do the same but right to left. It's relevant for Hebrew and Arabic languages.

Comment: Ok.. so I guess this has nothing to do with backbone.js (removed).

Comment: What do you mean by saying removed?

Comment: As you can see I removed it from the questions tags...

Answer (score 0):

After googling the question I've got nothing except the primitive hard coded examples.

The answer is:

```js
onTableDataScroll: function (e) {
            var offset = $(e.currentTarget).scrollLeft();

            if(UserSettings.get('direction').isRTL) {
                var bodyClientWidth = e.currentTarget.clientWidth;
                var tableBodyWidth = $(e.currentTarget).children('.table').outerWidth();
                e.data.$('.data_scroll_head table').css('margin-right', bodyClientWidth - tableBodyWidth + offset);
            } else {
                e.data.$('.data_scroll_head table').css('margin-left', -1 * offset);
            }

            e.data.options.offset = offset;
        },
```

I'm sure that example is very useful. The final formula is b**odyClientWidth - tableBodyWidth + offset**.